# Exchange duplicate mails

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are currently working on some kind of mailprocessing via EWS Exchange.

Now if two same mail messages are sent to two different users of the exchange, is there a way to recognize, that these two mails have some kind of semantic link ?

As a result we would like to process only of these mail messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange's own way to check for duplicate mails is this: For a given message, gather the tuple (Date Header, Message-Id Header, Recipient). If this tuple is recorded multiple times, the duplicate mails are silently dropped. Maybe you can use a similar approach.

Comment: Many thanks for t he information. Do you have a link to this topic ?